# jquerydatetimepicker not displaying on some iPhones

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I have this function running, but unfortunately the calendar is not displaying on some phones.

Is there something in my code blocking it from showing? I couldn't find a reason why it wouldn't work on only a select few phones.

Has anyone experienced this issue with jQuery datetimepicker? If so, what was the reason behind it?

```js
function createNewAppointment() {
  //set flow trigger actions
  bookingOptions.isCancel = false;
  bookingOptions.isReschedule = false;
  bookingOptions.isNewAppointment = true;

  //set customer details
  SetCustomerDetails();

  //set booking service notes
  SetBookingServiceNotes();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(bookingOptions),
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data.customers ? .length > 0) {
        AlertBox('Booking', 'Successfully created new booking', 'OK', '');
        // alert("Successfully created new booking"); 
        window.location.href = '/dashboard/'; //navigate user to dashboard.
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
      AlertBox('Booking', 'Error occured for create new booking', 'OK', '');
      //alert("Error occured for create new booking");
      $(".overlay").hide();
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('show');
      console.log(xhr);
    }
  });
}

function cancelAppointment() {
  $.post({
      url: url,
      data: JSON.stringify(bookingOptions),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      AlertBox('Booking', 'Successfully cancelled the appointment', 'OK', '');
      //   alert("Successfully deleted new appointment");
    });
}

function rescheduleAppointment() {
  //set flow trigger actions
  bookingOptions.isCancel = false;
  bookingOptions.isReschedule = true;
  bookingOptions.isNewAppointment = false;

  //set booking id
  bookingOptions.bookingId = "{{user.cr172_msbookingid}}";

  //set customer details
  SetCustomerDetails();

  //set booking service notes
  SetBookingServiceNotes();

  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(bookingOptions),
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
      AlertBox('Booking', 'Successfully rescheduled your booking', 'OK', '');
      // alert("Successfully rescheduled your booking"); 
      window.location.href = '/dashboard/'; //navigate user to dashboard.                   
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus) {
      AlertBox('Booking', 'Error occured for rescheduling your booking', 'OK', '');
      //alert("Error occured for rescheduling your booking");
      $(".overlay").hide();
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker('show');
      console.log(xhr);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: A first step would be to test if the datepicker works on its own - when you call it directly, outside all of the AJAX stuff that is going on here. Then you'd at least now whether it is a limitation of the chosen library, or a problem with your own coding around it.

Comment: did those tests, the picker is fine. Its this function.

Comment: So you are getting the alert message from within your success callback functions then, when you would expect those from the error callback?